# MDX - distinct count

Tags: count, distinct, ssas, mdx

I was following this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902637%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

and my query for distinct count looks like this:

```
Count(CrossJoin({[Measures].[Submission Count]}, [Submission].[PK Submission].Members), ExcludeEmpty)
```

it returns always 1 more than it should (for example it returns 27 instead of 26).

In the same article there is this query (which is suppose to solve this problem):

```
Count(CrossJoin( {[Sales]}, 
Descendants([Customers].CurrentMember, [Customer Names])),
 ExcludeEmpty)
```

But I can't get it to work. I've tried these two but second one always returns 1 or 0 while the first one doesn't work (error: I have to explicitly define a level):

```
Count(CrossJoin( {[Measures].[Submission Count]}, 
    Descendants([Submission].CurrentMember, [Submission].[PK Submission])),
     ExcludeEmpty)
```

```
Count(CrossJoin( {[Measures].[Submission Count]}, 
    Descendants([Submission].[PK Submission].CurrentMember, [Submission].[PK Submission])),
     ExcludeEmpty)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the first query returns "1 more than it should" is because the `[Submission].[PK Submission].Members` tuple set also includes the All member.

If you refer to the `[PK Submission]` level instead of all the members of the `[PK Submission]` hierarchy, it doesn't include the All member.

So, the following returns what you're expecting:

```
Count( CrossJoin( { [Measures].[Submission Count] }
                , { [Submission].[PK Submission].[PK Submission] })
     , ExcludeEmpty)
```